# Keep getting error message on k3b when trying to burn a dvd video of a movie

Tags: dvd, burning, k3b

when im burning a movie i keep getting this error message

[image]

I then clicked on SHOW DEBBUGING OUTPUT and it showed this message

```
Devices
-----------------------
TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L632H D400 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite] [%7]

K3b::IsoImager
-----------------------
mkisofs print size result: 0 (0 bytes)

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.8.5 (4.8.5)
QT Version:  4.8.1
Kernel:      3.2.0-60-generic-pae

Used versions
-----------------------
mkisofs: 1.1.11

mkisofs
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage: No such file or directory. Failed to open VIDEO_TS.IFO
/usr/bin/genisoimage: Can't open VMG info for '/tmp/kde-robert/k3bVideoDvd0/'.
/usr/bin/genisoimage: Unable to parse DVD-Video structures.
/usr/bin/genisoimage: Could not find correct 'VIDEO_TS' directory.
Possible reasons:
  - VIDEO_TS subdirectory was not found on specified location
  - VIDEO_TS has invalid contents

mkisofs calculate size command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -print-size -quiet -volid Frozen.2013.1080p.BluRay.x264.YI -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2010 SEBASTIAN TRUEG AND MICHAL MALEK -publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/kde-robert/k3bPR5701.tmp -no-cache-inodes -udf -iso-level 1 -path-list /tmp/kde-robert/k3bJw5701.tmp -dvd-video -f /tmp/kde-robert/k3bVideoDvd0
```

I need some help i am using QBITTORENT to download the movies. I am not using this to make money i am using it for personal watching.

Comment: Follow the error `/usr/bin/genisoimage: No such file or directory.` in `mkisofs`. Either kb3 didn't properly make that file during installation or it's trying to create it when burning and can't for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have this error each time I use K3b. To overcome this I find I need to go into the preferences where it asks for the path to the "tmp" folder. When clicking OK, it asks for permission to create the folder. I also find that I need to redo the file permissions to my CD/DVD writer as well.

It then works well. The only thing is to remmeber to do these two things each time I use it.